# C segfault calling strcat in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, strcat

I'm getting a segfault when trying to concat to strings using strcat in c. The error in gdb is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 1 (LWP 1)]
0xff1692b4 in strcat () from /lib/libc.so.1
```

The relevant code is below. I am malloc-ing the passed in char * returnedString in the calling function, and the initial value passed in to returnedString is just " ".

```
char * printPostOrder(struct block * node, char * returnedString)
 {
 char * temp;
   temp = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
  temp[0]='\0';
if(temp){
if (node != NULL)
{
    returnedString = printPostOrder(node -> left,returnedString);
    returnedString = printPostOrder(node -> right,returnedString);

    if (node -> left == NULL || node -> right == NULL)
    {
        if (node -> flag == 1)
        {
            sprintf(temp,"(%dA)\0",node -> size);
            strcat(returnedString,temp);
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(temp,"(%dF)\0",node -> size);
            //printf("%c",temp);
            strcat(returnedString,temp);

        }

    }
free(temp);
}
}

return returnedString;

}
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Where's your base case? You're probably *out of memory* because it never *stops* making new nodes. Your stack is too big.

Comment: I'm not making nodes, I'm traversing through existing nodes, to print out the size. I think the function is only called again if the node is not NULL?

Comment: You don't need to do `returnedString = strcat(returnedString, ...)`, since `strcat` just returns `retrurnedString` anyways. So you're effectively doing `returnedString = returnedString;`. However, this is just a side note. That's not the cause of your segfault.

Comment: You're not freeing `temp` when you're done with it.  Other than that, are there possibly enough nodes that `returnedString` might be too short?  `strcat()` won't allocate more space if the new string doesn't fit...

Comment: Now you're freeing temp twice, and you're still overrunning the top-level buffer.  Also, you aren't freeing temp in the case where the node is NULL.

Comment: Just use a global variable `length`, and before each `strcat` do: length += strlen(temp); if(length > 10000){printf("Error \n"); exit(1);}

Comment: Using a global is a terrible idea, *especially* since his program is apparently multithreaded, as evidenced by the `Switching to Thread 1` message he got after the segfault. If he's intending to use this function from multiple threads, he will have just made things much worse by using a global.

Comment: @MikeHolt Global variables and multithreading is indeed evil! But, in this situation `length` is being accessed only by `printPostOrder()` function.

Comment: @valter Yes but who's to say that `printPostOrder()` is only being accessed by a single thread? That was my whole point. Besides, global variables are not only evil when combined with multithreading. They're also bad (mostly) in single threaded applications as well, and really should be avoided, for a variety of reasons which you can easily Google. Having said that, I don't advocate against *all* use of globals. It's not a black and white issue to me. But the usage you've suggested strikes me as a lazy and error-prone way to patch a weak design, instead of actually *fixing* the design.

Answer (score 2):

First, these two lines

```
char * temp;
temp = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
```

should be replaced with this line

```
char temp[50];
```

otherwise, you leak 50 bytes of memory every time that function is called.

Second, at the top level, `returnedString` should be declared as

```
static char returnedString[1000000];
```

since you are almost certainly overrunning the buffer that you `strcat` into.

By way of explanation, the documentation for `strcat` says, "The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the result."  Note that `s1` is the first argument to `strcat`, i.e. the output buffer.  `strcat` won't manage memory for you, and it won't make the output buffer bigger.  It just crashes if the output buffer isn't big enough. Therefore, you need to make sure that you start with a large output buffer.  You can `malloc` that buffer, or just declare it statically as I've shown above, but you need to make sure it's big enough to hold the final result.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you're not calling `free(temp)` anywhere.

The best case is that this is just eating up a bunch of memory, but otherwise not causing any problems.

The worst case is that (depending on the size of the tree you are traversing and how much memory you have available) you are actually running out of memory. And since you're not checking whether `malloc()` returned `NULL`, you would then be passing a `NULL` pointer to `sprintf()`, which could very well be the cause of your segfault.

Comment: I'm calling free now and also checking if malloc is successful. Still getting the issue. I've updated my code above

Comment: In that case, I'd be inclined to think Dmitri's observation might be correct. Perhaps you haven't allocated enough memory for `returnedString`.

Comment: By the way, you need to put the `free(temp)` *after* the closing bracket for the `if (node != NULL)` condition. In other words, do `if (temp) { if (node != NULL) { ... } free(temp); }`, not `if (temp) { if (node != NULL) { ...  free(temp); } }`

Comment: Here's my allocation of returnedString. There is surely way more than enough memory since the first time it's called i'm only traversing 3 nodes                                                              char * returnedString;
    returnedString = (char *)malloc(10000 * sizeof(char));

Comment: Have you used a debugger to identify the exact line it's segfaulting on?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough memory allocated for the "returned string", I suggest something like this:

```
    char * printPostOrder(struct block * node, char * returnedString)
    {
            if (node != NULL)
            {
                    returnedString = printPostOrder(node -> left,returnedString);
                    returnedString = printPostOrder(node -> right,returnedString);

                    if (node -> left == NULL || node -> right == NULL)
                    {
                            if (node -> flag == 1)
                            {
                                    returnedString += sprintf(returnedString, "(%dA)",node -> size);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    returnedString += sprintf(returnedString, "(%dF)",node -> size);
                            }
                    }
            }
            return returnedString;
    }
```

snprintf returns the number of chars written, so this way you can keep this pointer pointing to the end of the string all the time. Each time you write there, you effectively append to the end of the original string.
Still, the "assuming you have enough memory allocated for the returned string" is important.

A note on strcat(str0, str1): it doesn't know where str0 ends, so each time you call it, it loops over the chars in str0 to find the end. Just updating a pointer to the current end of the string seems much nicer to me, than recomputing the length all the time.

Comment: You don't really want to be doing `returnedString += sprintf(...)` if the calling function is doing anything with the return value. Then again, There's really no need for it to do so, as it can just check the value that it passed in. Other than that, I agree it's better than `strcat`.

Comment: Well, returning something that the function is guaranteed to never change is pointless anyways, someone using a function would expect:

1) either doesn't return the char* I gave it

2) it returns something, probably because it possibly changed

Who would rely on a function not changing a pointer? You could do `nop` without a function

Comment: I agree that it is pointless to have returned the string in the first place. I'm just pointing out that if the calling function goes something like `printf("%s\n", printPostOrder(node, str));`, then it's going to skip the first few bytes of the string. Edit: It's not *necessary* to return the string, but lots of functions do this for convenience purposes, so that the function call can be embedded as an argument to another function, as in `printf("%s\n", strcat(...));`. This is the exact reason why `strcat` returns the same string you passed in.

Comment: Thanks @BuellaGábor. I've tried that and i'm getting a different segfault:                                                        [Switching to Thread 1 (LWP 1)]
0xff19a298 in _ndoprnt () from /lib/libc.so.1
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xff19a298 in _ndoprnt () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xff19de58 in sprintf () from /lib/libc.so.1

Comment: Your backtrace mentions sprintf, this could mean sprintf tries to write to wrong place in memory. Most of us here suspect your orignally allocated memory for *returnedString is too small. Probably this should be allocated dynamically. Also, use a debugger if you have one, and observe things step-by-step.

Comment: My returned string is being allocated with     returnedString = (char *)malloc(10000 * sizeof(char));
 I really can't see it taking any more memory than that, and i've played around with higher values

Comment: If you don't have a debugger to help you, you can do some ugly, manually-print-debug-info things, as @valter suggested.
insert a lot of printf calls temporarily in your function, using some global variables, as: int count = 0; printf("current count: %d\n", ++count);   also one for keeping track of string length, also one printf("current size: %d\n",node -> size); etc.. we don't see the rest of your code, so we can't help you much more

Comment: A little note on `returnedString = (char *)malloc(10000 * sizeof(char));` <-  sizeof(char) is 1 by definition in C standard

Comment: Using some debugging prints and gdb I am getting this output             `#0  0xff130d3c in memchr () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xff19ceb4 in _ndoprnt () from /lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xff19de58 in sprintf () from /lib/libc.so.1
#3  0x00010c78 in printPostOrder (node=0x219ac, returnedString=0x0) at temp.c:61
#4  0x00010bfc in printPostOrder (node=0x21974, returnedString=0x115a0 "") at temp.c:54
#5  0x00010bfc in printPostOrder (node=0x21958, returnedString=0x115a0 "") at temp.c:54
#6  0x000112b4 in getInput () at temp.c:199
#7  0x00011484 in main () at temp.c:235` Any ideas?

Comment: This says `returnedString=0x0` in the last call to printPostOrder, so something did overwrite it with `NULL` . Can you show the current full code of this function?

Comment: @BuellaGábor  Yeah that's what I noticed. I'm trying to debug it, but I'm still confused.  [My full code is here](http://pastebin.com/iS8LC3iZ) thanks so much for your help!

Comment: oh, in this the function starts  with `if(node ==NULL) { return; }` I don't know why your compiler doesn't scream at you for this, or if it is valid C at all. Anyways, I think you should return the original pointer here, just writing `return;` probably returns `NULL`

Comment: @BuellaGábor  Ah of course! That makes sense. I'm unsure what you mean by return origional pointer? I'm trying             return returnedString = &returnedString[0]; but still getting a segfault

Comment: Here's the stack: 0xff19a298 in _ndoprnt () from /lib/libc.so.1
#0  0xff19a298 in _ndoprnt () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xff19de58 in sprintf () from /lib/libc.so.1
#2  0x00010c74 in printPostOrder (node=0x219c4, returnedString=0x115b0 "Q") at temp.c:64
#3  0x00010bf4 in printPostOrder (node=0x2198c, returnedString=0x115b0 "Q") at temp.c:55
#4  0x00010bf4 in printPostOrder (node=0x21970, returnedString=0x115b0 "Q") at temp.c:55
#5  0x000112b0 in getInput () at temp.c:202
#6  0x00011480 in main () at temp.c:238

Comment: I meant just `return returnedString;` as you do it in the end of the function.

Comment: can you pastebin the current code for a last time, and I go to sleep pretty soon

Comment: @BuellaGábor  Here's the current code http://pastebin.com/NwKj6b0E Thankyou SO much for your help!

Comment: ok, the `returnedString` variable is ok according to your last backtrace. So something else might be wrong. For example: `#define memory 4096` after which `struct block blockArr[64];` and in findSpace: `for (i = 0; i < memory; i++)` ( also, findSpace doesn't return after the loop, if you are out of memory ( which seems to be really 64, not 4096 ) weird things can happen. Read all your code carefully, and try make sure it is consistent, and you handle error cases. Please turn on all warnings in your compiler, and fix everything till there is no warning left -- we usually do that in C . Goodluck